# How to hold place when reading a file in C++?

Tags: c++, file, ifstream

My infile.txt reads:

```
January 31
February 28
March 31
April 30
May 31
June 30
July 31
August 31
September 30
October 31
November 30
December 31
```

I need to create two functions: one that collects each month from the file (one month at a time), and another that collects the number of days in each month. This is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

string read_month_name();
int read_num_days();

int main() {
  string month_name;
  int num_of_days;

  ifstream myfile;
  myfile.open("infile.txt");

  for ( int i = 0; i < 12; ++i ) {
      month_name = read_month_name();
      num_of_days = read_num_days();
      cout << "There are " << num_of_days << " days in " << month_name << ".\n";
  }
}

string read_month_name() {
  string month;
  ifstream myfile;
  myfile.open("infile.txt");
  myfile >> month;
  return month;
}

int read_num_days() {
  int days;
  ifstream myfile;
  myfile.open("infile.txt");
  myfile >> days;
  return days;
}
```

The problem is that every time I read the file, I only ever collect "January"; as both a string and an integer. Therefore my output looks like this:

```
  There are 0 days in January.
  There are 0 days in January.
  There are 0 days in January.
  There are 0 days in January.
  There are 0 days in January.
  There are 0 days in January.
  There are 0 days in January.
  There are 0 days in January.
  There are 0 days in January.
  There are 0 days in January.
  There are 0 days in January.
  There are 0 days in January.
```

Is there a way I can insert a placeholder in my infile.txt so that I always pick up reading where I left off?

> P.S. I know that I can solve this by reading from the file in the main() function instead of in subprograms, but ***I need to find a way to make it work with the two subprograms.***

Comment: Open file only once and pass the ifstream as reference to each subroutine

Comment: To answer literally, you could use tellg and seekg, but that's a bad idea. Instead look into getline, and then pass that whole line to the function, where you parse with std::stringstream.

Comment: @KillzoneKid Can you please explain?

Comment: Start by declaring your functions to take your stream by reference: `string read_month_name(ifstream & myStream) {`

Comment: You should read the file once into a `std::vector` of structures and pass the vector to your functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help, but the answer was a lot more simple than I thought. I simply needed to declare myfile outside of the main function and only open the file *once* inside of the main function. The problem was that I opened my file in the main function and in each subfunction. The code below functions exactly as I need it to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

string read_month_name();
int read_num_days();

ifstream myfile;

int main() {
  string month_name;
  int num_of_days;

  myfile.open("infile.txt");

  for ( int i = 0; i < 12; ++i ) {
      month_name = read_month_name();
      num_of_days = read_num_days();
      cout << "There are " << num_of_days << " days in " << month_name << ".\n";
  }
}

string read_month_name() {
  string month;
  myfile >> month;
  return month;
}

int read_num_days() {
  int days;
  myfile >> days;
  return days;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`ifstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/) like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  string month_name;
  int num_of_days;
  ifstream infile("infile.txt");

  while (infile >> month_name >> num_of_days)
    cout << "There are " << num_of_days << " days in " << month_name << ".\n";
}
```

The result is what you are expecting.

**EDIT:**

Based on the comment that is requested the both `read_month_name` and `read_num_days`, this is how I would do it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

string read_month_name(string line);
string read_num_days(string line);

int main() {
  string str, month_name, num_of_days;
  ifstream file("infile.txt");

  for ( int i = 0; i < 12; ++i ) {
    getline(file, str);
    month_name = read_month_name(str);
    num_of_days = read_num_days(str);
    cout << "There are " << num_of_days << " days in " << month_name << ".\n";
  }

  return 0;
}

string read_month_name(string line){
  string month = "";

  for(int i = 0; i < line.size(); ++i) {
    if(line[i] == ' '){
      month = line.substr(0, i);
    }
  }

  return month;
}

string read_num_days(string line){
  string days = "";

  for(int i = 0; i < line.size(); ++i) {
    if(line[i] == ' '){
      days = line.substr(i, line.size());
    }
  }

  return days;
}
```

Comment: This works, but it makes the two subfunctions obsolete. I need to find a way to do it using both subfunctions.

Comment: You need to have in your solution this two functions??

Comment: Yes. I need both.

Comment: @JoiMcClain take a look at my version using both functions. Let me know if that is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to read a `.txt` file formatted `string` `int` and have to use 2 subroutines, one for each type. Additionally you want to be able to set number of lines to read.

First of all, you need to open file only once because if you open and close and open again you will start reading from the start losing the progress. So opening once means you will have to pass this opened stream around first to one function then to another etc. This creates a problem when you want to return value from such function, because you have to be able to tell if read was successful. You can do so by returning bool instead and filling the resulting variable via reference.

I added break when there is nothing left to read even if you have some iterations left (see the loop set to 20 but reads only 12)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

bool read_month_name(std::ifstream &, std::string &);
bool read_num_days(std::ifstream &, int &);

int main() {

    // make test file
    std::ofstream ofs("infile.txt");
    ofs << R"(January 31
February 28
March 31
April 30
May 31
June 30
July 31
August 31
September 30
October 31
November 30
December 31)";
    ofs.close();


    std::string month_name;
    int num_of_days;

    std::ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("infile.txt");


    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) 
    {
        if (read_month_name(myfile, month_name) && read_num_days(myfile, num_of_days))
            std::cout << "There are " << num_of_days << " days in " << month_name << ".\n";
        else
            break;
    }
}

bool read_month_name(std::ifstream &myfile, std::string &month)
{
    return myfile >> month ? true : false;
}

bool read_num_days(std::ifstream &myfile, int &days)
{
    return myfile >> days ? true : false;
}
```

Working demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=805dffae9f9ea13f